# Problema com fadeOut do jQuery!

Tags: jquery, html, css

Pessoal to com um probleminha aqui já tentei resolver de varias formas porem nada... Estou tentando fazer um PRELOADER que ira aparecer antes de carregar a página o problema é que mesmo depois que a página é carregada ele continua não some..
tenho o seguinte código

```
HTML:

<div id="preloader"></div>

CSS:

#preloader{
  position: fixed;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  z-index: 999;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: $white url("../img/loading.gif") no-repeat center center;
  background-size: 80px;
}

jQuery:

$(window).load(function() {
  $("#preloader").delay(500).fadeOut("slow").remove();
});
```

Comment: tente só `$('#preloader').fadeOut("slow");`

Comment: já tentei num deu tbm...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode usar o evento `document.onreadystatechange`. Quando ele for acionado basta verificar o status, se ele estiver `complete`, esconde o `#preloader`, segue exemplo:

```
document.onreadystatechange = function () {
   if (document.readyState == "loading") {
      //Mantem o #preloader visivel
   }else if(document.readyState == "complete") {
      $("#preloader").fadeOut("slow");
   }
}
```

Comment: Legal brother, funcionou da forma esperada. agradeço!

Comment: Por nada meu amigo!

Answer (score 1):

Você está chamando o callback errado no evento de janela errado, tente igual a este fiddle aqui (fiz umas modificações simples para não usar URL): https://jsfiddle.net/5t014jy0/

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#preloader").delay(500)
  .fadeOut("slow", function() { 
    return $("#preloader").remove() 
  })
});
```

Comment: Cara do jeito que vc passou deu certo.. porem ele mostra a página enquanto uma imagem ainda está carregando, coloquei uma imagem pesada pra testar.. ainda vou minifica-la.. tem alguma solução?

Comment: É uma questão de ajustar o tempo do seu delay eu acredito, ou usar a resposta do Lucas